# Error when scheduled build in Agent queue tries to sync repository

Tags: tfs, build, repository, build-agent, getlatest

I am using an TFS agent to schedule some Build using triggers. My issue is that when the build starts it wants to get latest version (sync repository). But I get an unusual error: 
[image]

I have literally no ideea where to begin, it's like it could reach the server or something.

Comment: the server was down, problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I could not comment. Hence providing an answer.

Does the account your agent is running under, has rights to the TFS repository mapped in the build?

For more logs check the logs in D:\Kits\agent_diag folder.